# Translating routes with action parameter using RouteLocalization.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2, attributerouting

Working off of this example:

```
[Route("MyActionWithStringParameter/{parameter}")]
ActionResult MyAction(string parameter)

.ForAction(x => x.MyAction(), new [] { typeof(string) })
```

From the GitHub documentation for RouteLocalization.Mvc.
https://github.com/Dresel/RouteLocalization/blob/master/Documentation/SelectingAndTranslatingRoutes.md

I cannot get my own code to work.

Here's my default route:

```
[Route("~/{slug:regex((bookreviews)-[^-]+-(\\d+))}")]
```

Here's how I initialize the translations in RouteConfig:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        var specificCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.Name);
        var region = new RegionInfo(specificCulture.Name);

        const string en = "en";
        ISet<string> acceptedCultures = new HashSet<string>() { en, "se", "dk" };
        routes.Localization(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.DefaultCulture = en;
            configuration.AcceptedCultures = acceptedCultures;
            configuration.AttributeRouteProcessing = AttributeRouteProcessing.AddAsNeutralAndDefaultCultureRoute;
            configuration.AddCultureAsRoutePrefix = false;
            configuration.AddTranslationToSimiliarUrls = false;
        }).TranslateInitialAttributeRoutes().Translate(localization =>
        {
            localization.AddRoutesTranslation(region.TwoLetterISORegionName.ToLower());
        });

        CultureSensitiveHttpModule.GetCultureFromHttpContextDelegate = Localization.DetectCultureFromBrowserUserLanguages(acceptedCultures, en);
```

And here's the translation in question:

```
localization.ForCulture(culture)
            .ForController<UserController>()
            .ForAction(x => x.UserReviews(), new[] { typeof(string) })
            .AddTranslation(ConfigurationHelper.AppSetting<string>("Route.User.UserReviews"));
```

With my value from web.config:

```
~/{slug:regex((boganmeldelser)-[^-]+-(\\d+))}
```

But I get a compiler error on this line:
`ForAction(x => x.UserReviews(), new[] { typeof(string) })`, that x.UserReviews required the formal parameter 'slug'. Which makes sense.

How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this when trying to solve the same issue.

Have just managed to get the following alternative to work, by using string value for action rather than linq expression. The string is the action method name and not an annotated route name.

```
   localization.ForCulture("en")
                .ForController<TestController>()
            .ForAction("TestMethod", new[] { typeof(int) })
             .AddTranslation("TranslatedTest/TranslatedTestMethod/{id}");
```